# How do I check security settings using Google Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I'm trying to display a warning message for Google Drive files that have undesirable access settings. This code (snippet) is not working:

```
    var security = DriveApp.getFileById(my_id).getSharingAccess();
    switch (security) {
      case "PRIVATE":
        Browser.msgBox("WARNING: This file is currently PRIVATE. Please update the sharing options to make it available to other users.");
        break;
```

If I display the variable "security" in a message box it displays "PRIVATE", but I don't think `getSharingAccess()` returns a string so I'm not sure how to test for it.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your snippet is missing a closing brace.

Secondly, for others reading this, this code snippet implicitly assumes it's running as a part of a script bound to a spreadsheet (the *browser.msgbox()* call is required to be called from within that context to work).

That said, here's my suggestion:

```
function myFunc() {
      var security = DriveApp.getFileById(my_id).getSharingAccess();


      if (security == DriveApp.Access.PRIVATE){
        Browser.msgBox("WARNING: This file is currently PRIVATE. Please update the sharing options to make it available to other users.");
      } else if (security == DriveApp.Access.ANYONE_WITH_LINK){
      // etc.
      }
}
```

Your problem was in trying to use the *security* variable as a string - it's really an object even though Google App Script is sometimes intelligent enough to just simply parse it as a string when, for example, printing in to the console.

Therefore, you have to compare it to the access permissions explicitly to get the result you want.

I hope that helps!